# Is it possible to provide feedback on Unearthed Arcana after the end of the corresponding survey?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana

The *Unearthed Arcana* content published by *Wizards of the Coast* generally comes with a survey a few weeks after that allows feedback on the respective article. However, for most of the current UA content, this survey is already over (e.g. the *Mystic* class), while the features haven't been published yet in an official rulebook such as *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*.

**Is there an official place to provide further feedback?**

The only possibilities I could think of are tweeting to the designers, or reviewing on [DM's Guild](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/213033/Unearthed-Arcana-The-Mystic-Class-5e) - neither of which feel very promising.

Comment: In the concrete case I wanted to suggest improving the *Mystic* Discipline  *Iron Durability*, which has pretty weak 7-psi feature. That should, however, not influence the answer, which is why I'm adding this as a comment for anyone interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I can tell, once that survey has closed, there is no official channel to provide that feedback. You could use the standard contact link at http://company.wizards.com/content/contact-us
. They likely close it down so that their data doesn't change over time, for research purposes.